# How to convert object sent from angular into associative array in laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative-array

This is my array request that is received by back-end laravel. I want to insert a bulk of rows. But I should convert it into an associative array. How can I convert my received array data into the format I want.

Array of Objects that I want to convert:

```
[
  {
   "reservation_id": 25,
   "room_id": 1,
   "check_in_date": "2020-04-27 12:00:00",
   "check_out_date": "2020-04-30 12:00:00",
   "availability": false,
   "status": "booked",
   "booking_id": 26
 },
 {
  "reservation_id": 26,
  "room_id": 2,
  "check_in_date": "2020-04-27 12:00:00",
  "check_out_date": "2020-04-30 12:00:00",
  "availability": false,
  "status": "booked",
  "booking_id": 26
 }
]
```

dd($request->all()) gives me below value.

[image]

Comment: can you please add the response of `dd($arrayOfObjects)`?

Comment: It shows null value. I did not get it..

Comment: please try `dd($request->all());` instead

Comment: I got the above result..

Comment: no need for json_decode() then - you can see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json_decode for that:

```
MyModel::insert($request->all());
```

Comment: "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given" I got this error while using this query.    json_decode(request()->all(), true)

Comment: Tq so much @Christophe ... It is working.. Tq alot.  :)

Comment: anytime! Glad to be of any help 